# Old Telerik controls (radtab) not recognized by ID attribute after upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Inherited an old web app with Telerik controls. When it was built (2007?), the radtab could use the ID attribute. I opened it up in VS 2015 and made some modifications to the web.config to get it up and running.

The aspx file has many lines that look like this:

```
<telerik:RadTab ID="tabReferrals" runat="server" Text="Referred To Entities" PageViewID="pvReferrals" ></telerik:RadTab>
```

The cs file references the control using the ID attribute like this:

```
tabReferrals.Visible = true;
```

From what I've read, the ID attribute is no longer used which is why I'm seeing this warning:

```
 Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'ID' is not a valid attribute of element 'RadTab'.
```

The question is, what do I have to do to port this and get it running? I can't find anything that replaces the ID attribute.

Comment: what version of .net were you running for the project that was built in? either run the project using vs2008 or make he necessary code changes running it under vs2015, consult with telerik support on updated controls / dll's also `ID should probably be id` lowercase

Comment: just use the Value property instead of the ID property in this case

Comment: Should RadTab be RadTabStrip? A RadTab can have a collection of RadTab controls.

Comment: Turns out this was due to a reference to the RadScriptManager in the Master page.